# How do I quickly draw a map

Tags: dictionary, mapping, vector-graphics

I am trying to export the layers (land, street, street names) separately from either google maps, openstreetmap.org, maperitive.net (or if you have a better recommendation).

The end goal is to have a custom marked up map but I need to make sure the land is the same and most of the roads line up. Any recommendations out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the raw XML data from OpenStreetMap for your area. For anything other than a tiny area, this might be a huge file. There's an API for this but you don't mention a language but I know there's bindings to Python and R.

Once you've done that, extract the bits you want according to the OSM data definition - basically you select XML elements by attribute tags using whatever XML parser is included in whatever language you are using.

Then you'll have a vector data set which you need to render as a map. For that you can use Mapnik, which is what OpenStreetMap use to put labels in the right place, draw good-looking lines etc etc.

This is all pretty hard work. Maybe you could just use some maps from an existing provider? It sounds like you want something simple - have you tried Stamen.com's 'Toner' map?

http://maps.stamen.com/toner/#12/37.7619/-122.3930